# Mysql data partitioning and trimming

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Our main table, tblLink, will have its primary key as foreign in a few other tables too and one of the tables will be tblMainData which over time will be millions of rows.

We would like to maintain only 3 months of data based on the insert date in tblLink.

The rest we would like to purge and keep to generate history reports. What is the best mechanism to go about in this scenario? Below is how our table structures looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblLink` (
  `linkID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `compID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `vehicleID` int(5) NOT NULL,  
  `deviceID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `locationFromID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `locationToID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `employeeIDInsert` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `dateTimeInsert` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateTimeStartJourney` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateTimeEnd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dateTimeEndJourney` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',   
  `linkStatus` enum('a','d','e','m') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`linkID`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblEmailLog` (
  `emailLogID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `linkID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `alertCodeID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userEmail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `alertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `alertInsertDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emailLogID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblEventAlert` (
  `eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `mainDataID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `vehicleID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `eventAlertSentEmail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventAlertMessage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventAlertID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblMainData` (
  `mainDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `linkID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `header` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `deviceSerialNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `speed` float NOT NULL,
  `course` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `dateTimer` datetime NOT NULL,
  `gpsDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `insertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `odoMeter` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `driverID` int(5) NOT NULL, 
  `eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mainDataInsertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `gpsString` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mainDataID`),
  KEY `dateTime` (`dateTimer`),
  KEY `linkID` (`linkID`),  
  KEY `eventAlertID` (`eventAlertID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblSubData` (
  `subDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mainDataID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `linkID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deviceSerialNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `subdeviceSerialNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dateTimer` datetime NOT NULL,
  `eventType` varchar(2) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`subDataID`),
  KEY `mainDataID` (`mainDataID`),
  KEY `linkID` (`linkID`),
  KEY `eventAlertID` (`eventAlertID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement date range partitioning for each 3 months so that the performance will be improved and the queries for the 3 months data wont scan through the historical data .

Comment: I am kind of lost after going through different tutorials. So is it that for every month I must run a 3 month partitioning is it? Any further guide o how to go about thx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example .,

==

CREATE TABLE t2

(

dt DATE

)

PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(dt))

(

PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2007-01-01')),

PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2007-04-01')),

PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2009-07-01')),

PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)

);

==

Comment: in my case I have to partition each tables separately is it. Then drop them based on date? I have to rebuild the tables every 3 months is it? Would this cause any problem to me? If one of the tables do not have datetime field then this will be a problem too I guess?